# Google Sheets to send email with text of cell that is entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the spreadsheet, Column `J` has the Company Name requesting the pickup. What I would like is for the Company Name requesting the pickup to be the email body. This would be entered in cell `J10` for example.

This would need to be sent out only once when the Company Name is entered. I have set the script to run "onEdit".

Following is what I have so far, as you will see, the issue lies is Line 14 - `var body`:

```
/* This function send an email when a specified range is edited
 * The spreadsheets triggers must be set to onEdit for the function
 */
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Get Active cell
  var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  // Define Notification Details
  var recipients = "emailaddressn@domain.com";
  var subject = "Pickup Entered";
  var body = ss.getActiveSelection() + " has a pickup.";
  if (cellcol == 10) {
    // Send the Email
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
} // End sendNotification
```

So, in the end the drivers would receive an email from the Google sheet, with the Subject being "Pickup Entered" and the body of the email is "Company ABC has a pickup".

***Update:*** I found a similar script and modified it to suit. This works exactly how I want it to:

```
function sendNotification() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
if(sheet.getName()=='Sheet1'){
var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
var cellcol = cell.getColumn();
if(cellcol == 10){
var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
var recipients = "emailaddress@domain.com";
var subject = 'Pickup Requested '+cellvalue;
var body = 'A new Pickup has been placed for ' + cellvalue + '. Please 
coordinate with dispatch.';
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);}
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the range into HTML table first.

Notes:

- Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081844/5372400) on how to get HTML from a range.
- Use the proper syntax for active range: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`
- As you want the active range to send, the function will work properly from a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Sample code to get the menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Send selection', 'sendNotification')
      .addToUi();
}
```